# String formatting in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting

In a django app I am writing,I have created a MyEntry and MyCategory ,and given **unicode**() implementations for them.To represent an entry ,I am using a string built from an entry's category name,starttime and entry's creation date.

However ,when I try to list the entries,I am getting

```
['category1']13:02:542011-07-16

['category2','category3']18:21:342011-07-11

['category3']18:09:192011-07-11
```

This [] comes from the list comprehension I guess. I wish I could get the names like

```
 category2,category3-18:21:34-2011-07-11
 category3-18:09:19-2011-07-11
```

How should I implement **unicode**() for my models to get this effect? Can someone help?

My models are

```
from datetime import date
class MyCategory(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class MyEntry(models.Model):
    today=models.DateField(default=date.today)   
    starttime=models.TimeField(null=True)     
    categories=models.ManyToManyField(MyCategory)
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):        
        return "%s%s%s"%([str(x.name) for x in self.categories.all()],self.starttime,self.today)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace `"%s%s%s"%([str(x.name) for x in self.categories.all()],…)` with `"%s-%s%s" % (','.join(str(x.name) for x in self.categories.all()),…)`.